# Mascara de moeda, erro sem milhar, inputmask

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

Estou usando o plugin inputmask.

Tenho dois casos, quando eu seto 4.5 eu espero que a mascara apareça 4,50 e quando seto 10000.5 espero que ela me mostre 10.000,50. Porém o 4.5 me mostra 40,50 , como faço para mostrar 4,50? Já o caso de 10000.5 funciona corretamente me dando 10.000,50.

Fiddle Aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/xs0rLfto/25/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.value').click(function(){
   var dataValue= $(this).attr('data-value');
     $('#mask').val(dataValue);
  });
});

$('#mask').inputmask({
  digits: 2,
  digitsOptional: false,
  rightAlign: false,
  radixPoint: ",",
  groupSeparator: ".",
  alias: 'currency',
  prefix: " ",
  removeMaskOnSubmit: true,
  autoUnmask: true,
  numericInput: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Try to set 4.50 int into input value</p>

Currency : <input id="mask" type="text" />
<button class="value" data-value="4.5">
Set Value 4.50 Expect to be 4,50
</button>

<button class="value" data-value="10000.5">
Set Value 10000.50 Expect to be 10.000,50
</button>
```

Opções do plugin:

- digits: 2,
- digitsOptional: false,
- rightAlign: false,
- radixPoint: ",",
- groupSeparator: ".",
- alias: 'currency',
- prefix: " ",
- removeMaskOnSubmit: true,
- autoUnmask: true,
- numericInput: true

Comment: Primeira coisa: Aqui você só deveria postar em português, e não um texto frankenstein metade em português metade em inglês. Segunda coisa, o texto em português não bate com o inglês, embora sejam parecidos.

Comment: Por gentileza, verifique se a resposta dada resolve o problema ou dê um feedback.